# MySQL replication not finished on next site call

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, multi-master

I have 3 MySQL8.0 instances. Two of them are slaves. Each site call I‘m reading the slave till the first write Request is made. Afterwards Only the Master is used during the request. Now, if I write something into the database and redirect the user to a new page, the slave isn‘t updated yet. Is there any way I can handle such things?

Solutions I already found downgrade to MySQL 5.7 with Galera Cluster/Percona xtraDB/[Group Replication](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/02/15/group-replication-shipped-early/).

Any other ideas? Which would you prefer?

Comment: Since you are on 8.0, why not simply add on InnoDB Cluster?

Comment: I did'nt want to change too much on the environment. It's a legacy software which is migrating to PHP Symfony and therefore it's not optimized for database queries. Each site call does >600Req. Most of them are not needed, I guess. Our Goal was to be able to scale that over multiple vm's (Solr, Redis, PHP, MySQL, and more). Maybe it's the second step.

Comment: 600 req per day?  per second?

Comment: Splitting up tasks across VMs provides some level of isolation, but not scaling.

Comment: Group Replication and Galera are 'competing' technologies; have you managed to enable both on the same system?  Sounds scary.

Comment: No it‘s still like I mentioned above. It‘s only a Master-Slave set now. Without galera and group replication. Each www vm has its own slave. On another vm is the Master instance which is used once a write request is done. It‘s 600 per site call. 12.000 per second.

Comment: 12K writes/second?  Or 12K reads/second?

Comment: Reads... there are only a few write requests in a site call. Most of them only 1 if a session has been started.

Comment: Those solutions should work with 8.0.  In particular, InnoDB Cluster has a specific function call to hand the "critical read" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While an application-independent solution could be possible, in general, a **replication-aware application** could be much better, because you can use the high performance of asynchronous replication for most of the time, and only revert back to (slower) synchronous replication when it is needed.

This is not a theoretical method, we at Wikipedia use this model with specific code called "[chronology protector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MediaWiki_architecture#Database_and_text_storage)", which only gets triggered when an important event happens (e.g. an edit) and you don't want the user to be served outdated results.

In order to do this, **after doing your master writes, you should keep your master replication file and position** (if not using GTID), **or the GTID coordinates** (if using GTID) after your write (once the transactions has been commited on the master), and then on the replica connections, **wait until the server reaches those positions** or higher. There is some extra details to consider, such as when exactly to wait (on write or on read), for how long until you give a timeout (e.g. if replica breaks or lags), but that is highly dependent on your environement.

In terms of implementation, [`MASTER_POS_WAIT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_master-pos-wait) / [`WAIT_FOR_EXECUTED_GTID_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gtid-functions.html#function_wait-for-executed-gtid-set) are the functions commonly used for this.

Some of the clusters you mention give you shortcuts to perform this easier (e.g. Galera's causal reads), but the logic is similar- you don't want to be on fully consistent mode all the time; just forcing it when necessary.

Comment: MASTER_POS_WAIT works perfect! Thanks for the answer. I wouldn't have figured this out alone.

Comment: Thanks for the link about "chronology protector".  It seems somewhat complex, and perhaps more aimed at a site which expects 30-second lags as opposed to 1-second lags.

Comment: I don't disagree about the complexity, but I am curious why you think the second part of your comment? A 1-second lag will create around the same async issues than a 30 second one, there are points in which you need sync reads anyway. In fact, in our case, we are 99% on 0-1 seconds range as transactions larger than 1 second are killed automatically.

Comment: Same here... 99% are already replicated, when they are needed. BUT if you redirect your user after writing to somewhat like a result page, you need a synchronous database. For those cases we're now encrypting the information in a new cookie which is read at the next request.

That's a really quick implemented and scalable behaviour.